# Redirect the error to /dev/null

Tags: variable, error-handling

I have a shell script with the line

```
COMPRESS_OPTION=`which compress`
```

There is no `compress` utility installed in our server, hence it gives the error

```
which: no compress in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin)
```

on the screen. So I tried

```
COMPRESS_OPTION=`which compress 2>/dev/null`
```

Even then I am getting error on screen.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `which compress 2>/dev/null` returns nothing, as expected, when I test it. Maybe the error is coming from somewhere else in the script where `COMPRESS_OPTION` is expected to be a certain value. Also I need to know which error you are talking about.

Comment: No. I am getting this error which: no compress in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin) even if I redirect the error to /dev/null

Comment: What shell are you using? When I use `which` with a nonexistent command it doesn't print an error message.

Comment: Do you get an error line? Maybe the same command is called elsewhere.

Comment: `which` has many implementations, all different.  If you're using `bash` or a similar shell, try `type -path compress` instead (BTW, I have `alias which='type -path'` in my .bashrc).  Using `type -path` also has the advantage of only returning the FIRST program  it finds in the PATH - most `which` implementations return ALL matching program anywhere in the path.

Comment: BTW, another option is to use `command -v compress`.  This is the POSIX standard way to find out which binary will be executed if you run a command.  `type -path` is commonly available but not POSIX standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `which`, use the POSIX standard `command -v`.  For example:

```
COMPRESS_OPTION="$(command -v compress)"
[ $? != 0 ] && echo "compress not found" || echo "compress is $COMPRESS_OPTION"
```

If you don't want to change all the instances of `which` in your script, add a function like the following near the start:

```
which() {
  local w status
  w="$(command -v "$1")"
  status=$?
  [ -n "$w" ] && echo "$w"
  return $status
}
```